# How to initialize a bounded Vec

Tags: pallet

So I have this code here in my vesting pallet:

```
        #[pallet::weight(100)]
        pub fn modify_vesting_scheudule_block_for_all (
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            block_amount: <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber,
        ) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
            ensure_root(origin)?;
            let res = with_transaction_result (|| {
                let mut vested_ids = Vec::new();
                for (id,_schedules) in VestingSchedules::<T>::iter() {
                    vested_ids.push(id);
                }
                for id in vested_ids.iter() {
                    let schedules = VestingSchedules::<T>::take(id);
                    let mut tmp: BoundedVec<VestingScheduleOf<T>, T::MaxVestingSchedules>;
                    for schedule in &schedules {
                        if schedule.start < block_amount {
                            // need to put it back and revert the take if there is an error 
                            // VestingSchedules::<T>::insert(id, schedules.clone());
                            return Err(Error::<T>::InvalidClaimBlock.into());
                        };
                        // ensure!(schedule.start > block_amount, Error::<T>::InvalidClaimBlock);
                        tmp.push(
                            VestingSchedule {
                                start: schedule.start - block_amount,
                                period: schedule.period,
                                period_count: schedule.period_count,
                                vested_amount: schedule.vested_amount,  
                            }
                        );
                    }
                    VestingSchedules::<T>::insert(id, tmp);
                }   
                Ok(())
            });
            
            match res {
                Ok(_) => {
                    Self::deposit_event(Event::VestingScheduleModified(block_amount));
                    Ok(().into())
                },
                Err(_e) => {
                    Err(Error::<T>::InvalidClaimBlock.into())
                }
            }
            
        }
```

However I am getting this error:

```
error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `tmp`
   --> pallets/vesting/src/lib.rs:269:7
    |
269 | /                         tmp.push(
270 | |                             VestingSchedule {
271 | |                                 start: schedule.start - block_amount,
272 | |                                 period: schedule.period,
...   |
275 | |                             }
276 | |                         );
    | |_________________________^ use of possibly-uninitialized `tmp`
```

This makes sense to me but I have been searching around and I can not seem to find any documentation on how to actually intialize an empty bounded Vec. I have been using this as reference: https://docs.rs/bounded-vec/latest/bounded_vec/struct.BoundedVec.html. How do I initialize a bounded Vec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all types in Rust that can be default initialized you can use the `Default` trait:

```rust
let mut my_vec: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<10>> = Default::default();
```

Or equivalently

```rust
let mut my_vec = BoundedVec::<u8, ConstU32<10>>::default();
```

You can also use the macro

```rust
let mut my_vec: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<10>> = bounded_vec![];
```

Or omit the type and hope that the compiler figures it out:

```rust
let mut my_vec = bounded_vec![];
```

Comment: Thank you! Default::default(); worked like a charm